# PostgreSQL Labeling a Column

Tags: postgresql

```
select 'Top Query' as 'Query_Ran', coalesce(is_active, 'Actual NULL Value') as is_active, count(*) as row_count
from example
group by coalesce(is_active, 'Actual NULL Value')
```

I get the error message `"syntax error at or near "'Query_Ran'"`

Trying to label the top and bottom unions, what should the syntax be?

**Edit:** Can someone please explain to me why we are voting to close this question?

Comment: You need double quotes for the alias: `select 'Top Query' as "Query_Ran"`

Comment: My problem is now solved, thank you @Frank Heikens

Comment: If `Top Query` is actually a  column in the database it would need to be double quoted also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed single quotes before the "as" and double quotes for the alias.
Example:

select 'Top Query' AS "Query_Ran"

This fixed my problem.